# Finding maximum and minimum values of a two variable function (Two approaches, got stuck in the end)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

> Given the function $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$. 
> while $x$ and $y$ must be on the circle $x^2+y^2=16$ 
> Find the maximum and minimum points of the function $f(x,y)$.

I have used Lagrange multipliers setting lagrange function $\phi(x,y,\lambda)=x^4+y^4+\lambda(x^2+y^2-16)$, and got final answer $x= \pm \sqrt{8}$, $y= \pm \sqrt{8}$.  
And I was confused if I have found two points $((\sqrt{8} , \sqrt{8}), (- \sqrt{8}, - \sqrt{8}))$ or four points (all possible values), and wanted to make sure my solution is correct. 

So to test myself, I have decided to use another method and got stuck also, here's what I tried: 
Let $x=4\cos(t)$, $y=4\sin(t)$ while $2\pi \ge t \ge 0$.
 and I substitute that into the $f(x,y)$ to make sure the points I will find are on the circle. 
$u(t) = 256\cos(t)^4 + 256\sin(t)^4$. to find maximum and minimum I took derivative: 
$u'(t) = 1024 ( -\cos(t)^3\sin(t) + \sin(t)^3\cos(t) = 0$
$512 ( -\cos(t)^2\sin(2t) + \sin(t)^2\sin(2t)=0$ 
$512\sin(2t) (\sin(t)^2-\cos(t)^2) = 0$ 
So if $\sin(2t) = 0$ I got that $t = 0, \frac{\pi}{2},2\pi$ 
and here I got alot of different points that I don't know which of them are the true values and I feel lost in my calculations. 
I would love to hear feedback about my second approach, and to make sure if my answer in the first approach is true or not. 
Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: The first method will also return another set of $4$ points, so in total you have $8$ points. It is clear that one set of points return maximum and another minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine all possibilities of signs of your solutions for $x$ and $y$.

In your second approach you forgot some solutions, namely $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and the solutions $0$ and $2\pi$ of course are the same since the resulting points $(4\cos(x),4\sin(x))$ coincide.

Even further, the $sin^2-cos^2$ term also has some zeros. While these zeros correspond to what you've found in your first approach, the points you found in your second approach are missing in your first approach (Hint: In general, an equation $x^3-x=0$ has not only the solutions $x=\pm1$ but also the solution $0$.)

Comment: Thanks alot! great explanation and great hint that hit right the spot I fell in, if you have solved it and got your final answer I will appreciate to take it to try to reach it again after I got your help. I have tried to find some online graph calculator or normal calculator to check my answers before coming here but found none, do you have any recommended way to check my answers for these type of questions if there is?

Comment: I haven't computed anything, just by the symmetry of your problem you can see that the Lagrange-critical points must be $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ with $t\in\{\frac{2\pi k}{8}|k=0,...,7\}$ and you can distinguish minima and maxima by inserting these points to the function. To prove it you need to follow one of your approaches from above (I would recommend to you the first one).